# python check free disk space for remote addresses

Tags: python

I have made a script like this

```
import os

disk = os.statvfs("/home/")



print "~~~~~~~~~~calculation of disk usage:~~~~~~~~~~"

totalBytes = float(disk.f_bsize*disk.f_blocks)

print("Total space : {} GBytes".format(totalBytes/1024/1024/1024))

totalUsedSpace = float(disk.f_bsize*(disk.f_blocks-disk.f_bfree))


print("Used space : {} GBytes".format(totalUsedSpace/1024/1024/1024))

totalAvailSpace = float(disk.f_bsize*disk.f_bfree)


print("Available space : {} GBytes".format(totalAvailSpace/1024/1024/1024))
```

It checks all for my computer but I want to check for the remote address also from my computer by running this script. How can I do that? Like I want to check the space of my server then? Need help.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/), a tool that provides a high-level python API for executing SSH commands on remote servers.

```
from fabric.api import run

def disk_free():
    run('df -h')
```

Then you can run this command on any server:

```
server:misc$ fab disk_free -H vagrant@192.168.1.7

Executing task 'disk_free'
run: df -h
out: Filesystem                               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
out: /dev/sda1                                7.3G  3.3G  3.7G  47% /
out: tmpfs                                    927M     0  927M   0% /dev/shm
out: /vagrant                                 409G  339G   71G  83% /vagrant
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple xml rpc server with your function and deploy it on each remote node you want to check. Then you write a collection script to iterate over all nodes and fire your remote function.

Answer (score 0):

For a large number of remote machines, I recommend [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home). You have to predefined your list of hosts, but once you do it's as simple as:

```
ansible -m command -a 'df -h'
```